# Multiple using statements with if condition

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter, using-statement

I need to read one file and write processed data into one or optionally two files.

How to organize the Using statements in this case?
Will something like this work?

```
if (condition)
    using (var sw2 = StreamWriter(writeFile2))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(readFile))
using (var sw = StreamWriter(writeFile))
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    sw.WriteLine(line);
    if (condition)
        sw2.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Why not just include the using in the second if - before the sw2.WriteLine?

Comment: Something like `using (sw2 = condition ? new StreamWriter(writeFile2) : null)`should work. If the condition is not a trivial `bool` then remplace last `if (condition)` by `(if sw2 != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using blocks can handle a null fine. You can then do something like:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(readFile))
using (var sw = StreamWriter(writeFile))
using (var sw2 = condition ? new StreamReader(writeFile2) : null)
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    sw.WriteLine(line);
    sw2?.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Where I've moved the sw2 after the open stream reader so that the file won't get created if the opening of the read file fails, and used the "safe navigation operator" `?.` to handle the case of sw2 being null in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

No your code is not correct because if the condition is true then all the usings are considered as a single statement.
So you read/write all the files only when the condition is true.

Instead if you want to always read the *readFile* and write to the *writeFile* but write to *writeFile2* only if the condition is true then you need to clearly express your intention using the proper braces

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(readFile))
using (var sw = StreamWriter(writeFile))
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    sw.WriteLine(line);
    if (condition)
    {
        using (var sw2 = StreamWriter(writeFile2))
            sw2.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the writeFile2 be opened and closed for every line read in this case?

Comment: It seems that you are reading just one line. Do you have this code inside a loop? If yes, please show it (besides, also the _writeFile_ is created each time you call this code).

Comment: Sorry, Steve. I should have specified that the line reading is inside a loop.

Comment: OK, but in this way (if you don't change inside the loop the destination file) everytime you overwrite the file created in the previous loop with the content of the current line.

Comment: There is only one loop which is reading file line by line and writing to the other two.